# mongodb default value for document not in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to select id in array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`,
if there is no document with Id `3 and 5`, I want default name for this.

for example.

```
{id:1,name:a}
{id:2,name:b}
{id:4,name:c}
```

query something...

```
find ... id:{$in:{1,2,3,4,5}}})
```

->
result should be

```
{id:1,name:a}
{id:2,name:b}
{id:3,name:defaultvalue}
{id:4,name:c}
{id:5,name:defaultvalue}
```

i want default value for 3 and 5.

how should i query??
please help

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your use case using [MongoDB aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)

1. I started with [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) and created two arrays:

   - `missingIDs` to find out the missing IDs that are not in the documents
   - `matchedDocuments` to [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) all the available documents available in array [1,2,3,4,5]
2. Then concatenated these two arrays, and used [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) along with [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) to add a name field if null.

Try the following aggregation query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      missingIDs: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            ids: {
              $push: {
                id: "$id"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            ids: {
              $setDifference: [
                [
                  {
                    id: 1
                  },
                  {
                    id: 2
                  },
                  {
                    id: 3
                  },
                  {
                    id: 4
                  },
                  {
                    id: 5
                  }
                ],
                "$ids"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$ids"
        },
        {
          $project: {
            id: "$ids.id"
          }
        }
      ],
      matchedDocuments: [
        {
          $match: {
            id: {
              $in: [
                1,
                2,
                3,
                4,
                5
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            id: 1,
            name: 1,
            _id: 0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      concat: {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$matchedDocuments",
          "$missingIDs"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$concat"
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "concat.name": {
        "$ifNull": [
          "$concat.name",
          "defaultvalue"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      id: "$concat.id",
      name: "$concat.name",
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      id: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tDktdBrjOd5)

Answer (score 1):

The pipeline contains the following stages in order -

1. Start by [`matching`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) the `id` field
2. [`Group by`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) nothing so that you can [`accumulate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push) the result into [`an array`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) for later set comparison
3. Find the [`set-difference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) of what is missing and attach them to the temporary result set in the `$addFields` stage
4. Project both matched and missing values now
5. [`Concat them`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) both into a single array and project them
6. [`Unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array
7. [`Replace the root`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) so that you get your desired flat structure
8. [`Sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) by `id` field.

---

Here's the pipeline for your reference -

```
var idArr = [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5
];

db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            id: {
                $in: idArr
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            grouping: {
                $push: '$$ROOT'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            missingVals: {
                $setDifference: [
                    idArr,
                    {
                        $map: {
                            input: '$grouping',
                            as: 'item',
                            in: '$$item.id'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            result1: {
                $map: {
                    input: '$grouping',
                    as: 'item',
                    in: {
                        id: '$$item.id',
                        name: '$$item.name'
                    }
                }
            },
            result2: {
                $map: {
                    input: '$missingVals',
                    as: 'item',
                    in: {
                        id: '$$item',
                        name: ''
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            result: {
                $concatArrays: ['$result1', '$result2']
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$result'
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: '$result'
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            id: 1
        }
    }
]);
```

Outputting -

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "a"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "b"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": ""
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "c"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": ""
  }
]
```

[`MongoDb playground`](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WHn9IIfEtvU)

Answer (score 0):

- `$match` your ids `$in` condition
- `$group` by null and make array of all root objects and ids
- `$reduce` input as array of ids and initial value as root array of objects

  - check condition if id in ids array then return current value other wise add new default object and concat with `root` array using `$concatArrays`
- `$unwind` deconstruct root array
- `$replaceWith` to replace root object in root

```
let inputIds = [1,2,3,4,5];
let defaultValue = "defaultValue";

db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { id: { $in: inputIds } } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      root: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
      ids: { $push: "$id" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      root: {
        $reduce: {
          input: inputIds,
          initialValue: "$root",
          in: {
            $cond: [
              { $in: ["$$this", "$ids"] },
              "$$value",
              { $concatArrays: ["$$value", [{ id: "$$this", name: defaultValue  }]] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$root" },
  { $replaceWith: "$root" }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IniMOYCEZe8)